# Multiple characters and Hall of Monuments

Tags: guild-wars

In Eye of the North, there is a Hall of Monument that is part of the Guild Wars Beyond program to reward players for loyalty going into Guild Wars 2.

They mentioned that the points (of a max of 50) would be rewarded on an account-basis. Meaning that if your warrior was displaying 3 heroes in his fellowship monument, and your monk was displaying 2, you would get 5 points.

My question is, is that accurate even though the heroes unlocked on the monk and the warrior could be the same ?

Warrior : displaying Jora, Vekk and Livia
Monk : displaying Jora and Livia

would that display amount to 5 points, or 3 points ?

Same question for titles, pets, weapons and armor. Are the unlocks across the account mutually exclusive in their contribution.

Comment: Ooh, I hadn't thought of this?

Answer (score 4):

They are indeed mutually exclusive; everything you stick in your hall will only count once, including mini pets. You'll need 50 distinct ones to get all the points for it, as well as distinct armor sets for the armor monument and all heroes and special pets displayed in that particular monument as well.

Comment: "I assume since miniatures would be hard to fill without duplicates, they only categorize them by rarity, not by name. So by all means fill your monument with Whiptail Devourers, as long as you have one rare and one unique as well." My experience does not concurr with this. Minis displayed MUST be unique across all accounts.

Comment: That is entirely correct, and I wish I would have known that several months ago. Ah well, price of experience and all that; thanks for bringing this to my attention; I'd entirely forgotten it.

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to Artless's answer:

If you toggle your HoM to show account based achievements rather than per character, then it will be an accurate reflection of the bonuses that gets carried over to GW2.  So if you have Jora displayed twice on your warrior and monk, it is only shown once across the account.

This way, you can choose to obtain titles on different characters as long as they are not the same title, both will be counted towards your account wide monument.